# Why are Google cookies getting sent to third-party website even after completely cleaning my browser?

Tags: cookies, single-sign-on, session-cookies, cross-domain-policy

I just cleared all my browser's data and opened a new Incognito window.
I navigated to `askubuntu.com` and logged in.

Interesting, in one of the first requests cookies are getting sent back to `askubuntu` that appear to be of the Google Analytics style.

What I am wondering is how can cookies on one domain (Google) get sent to a third party domain (AskUbuntu) ?

[image: Ubuntu Cookies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is in your question: `"in one of the first requests cookies are getting sent back"`. If it's not the first request, then it's normal to have cookies sent back, since they would have been set earlier by Google Analytics.

What I see is that you have the `preserve logs` option on, and before the request to `askubuntu.com`, there are others requests, which tells me this is a subsequent request, not the first one.

Do this:

- Close/Reopen an incognito window
- Uncheck `preserve logs`
- Go to `askubuntu.com`

--> Look at the very 1st request to `askubuntu.com`, there won't be any GA cookies in it.